# Default values in relabel replacement

Tags: prometheus

In case the source_labels is empty or the regex doesn't catch anything, is it possible to set a default value for replacement?

For example for something like this:

```
    - source_labels:
      - __address__
      - __meta_openstack_tag_prometheus_io_port
      action: replace
      regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
      replacement: $1:$2
      target_label: __address__
```

If __meta_openstack_tag_prometheus_io_port is not defined, can I set $2 to a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to have a action after it like:

```
- source_labels: [__address__, __meta_openstack_tag_prometheus_io_port]
  regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;
  replacement: $1:default
  target_label: __address__
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in one step as far as I understand, but you can do it using a temporary label:

```
 - target_label: __tmp_port
   replacement: 42
 - source_labels: [__meta_openstack_tag_prometheus_io_port]
   target_label: __tmp_port
   regex: (\d+)
 - source_labels:
      - __address__
      - __tmp_port
      action: replace
      regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
      replacement: $1:$2
      target_label: __address__
```

First we set the default in `__tmp_port`, then overwrite it from `__meta_openstack_tag_prometheus_io_port` if possible, then use `__tmp_port` with either value for the final action.